# wordpress php can't combine string with code

Tags: php, wordpress, function

```
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_objects', 'my_wp_nav_menu_objects', 10, 2);

function my_wp_nav_menu_objects( $items, $args ) {

// loop
foreach( $items as &$item ) {

    // vars
    $image = get_field('menu_item_image', $item);


    // append image
    if( $image ) {

        $item->title .= '<img class="ttl" src="' . <?php echo 
$image['url']; ?> . '" alt="' . <?php echo $image['alt']; ?> . '" />';

    }

}


// return
return $items;

}
```

What am I doing wrong? New to PHP and WordPress functions. The problem seems to be in the append image section.

Comment: There are 2 errors on your code: `<?php echo $image['url']; ?>` should be `$image['url']`, and `<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>` should be `$image['alt']`. You use `echo` when you're going to display a string on screen right away, which isn't the case here: you're **assigning** a string to `$item->title`.

Comment: @cabrerahector that did it, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace this:

```
$item->title .= '<img class="ttl" src="' . <?php echo 
$image['url']; ?> . '" alt="' . <?php echo $image['alt']; ?> . '" />';
```

for this

```
$item->title .= '<img class="ttl" src="' .$image['url']. '" alt="' . $image['alt'] . '" />';
```

you cannot use this `<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>` `inside echo '...'`

Reference: [http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php](https://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php)